# Why the post method does not send the json to API Rest in QT5?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to send a json via a post request QT5. This is my situation. I have a Parser class that takes a QByteArray, always with different values, from another class through the SIGNAL and SLOT. But I want to take only certain values, which when taken, send them to another method of the same parser class where sending them to API Rest. Unfortunately the json is not sent to my app.

This is my **Header.h**

```
...
class Parser : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Parser();

public slots:
    void receivePackage(QByteArray &sendBuffer);

public:
    ...    
    QByteArray bufferToParse;
    QByteArray bufferToPacket;
    QQueue<QByteArray> queue;
    void sendPacketToAPI(QByteArray &bufferToPacket);

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *m_manager;
    quint8 m_a;
    quint8 m_b;
};
```

This is my **parser.cpp**

```
Parser::Parser()
    : m_manager { new QNetworkAccessManager }
{
}

void Parser::receivePackage(QByteArray &sendBuffer){
    queue.enqueue(sendBuffer);
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        bufferToParse = queue.dequeue();
        ...
        for (int i = 6; i < 262; i++) {
            bufferToPacket.append(bufferToParse.at(i));
        }
    sendPacketToAPI(bufferToPacket);
    ...        
}

void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    reply->deleteLater();
    qDebug() << "reply delete!";
    qDebug() << "https post_request done!";
}


void Parser::sendPacketToAPI(QByteArray &bufferToPacket) {
    m_a = bufferToPacket.at(0);
    m_b = bufferToPacket.at(1);
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl ("https://..."));
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
    QObject::connect(m_manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, replyFinished);
    QString json = QString("{\"speed\":\"%1\",\"acceleration\":\"%2\"}").arg(m_a).arg(m_b);
    m_manager->post(request, json.toUtf8());
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at your data with a debugger? I don't think that you're using the bufferToPacket array correctly. m_a and m_b are not what you think. Take a look there for a start.

Comment: @johnelemans yes, I print the m_a and m_b values with qDebug () and they are exactly what I expect.

Comment: hmmm. the rest looks good (looks like my code which works). What's showing up on the server?

Comment: in my app don't see any data.  I don't understand...

Comment: you should be able to see the result of the call in the server logs. it will show what is sent. Your reply should also show the server error or response code.

Comment: the server logs do not show no request or error. it is as if even called departed

Comment: Try replacing the connect command with;  connect(m_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply *))); and see what comes back in the reply.

Comment: nothing changes. I tried to separate the two pieces of code; in other words I created another project where only do the post request, and it works! I use the same methods, but hereit doesn't works